# loop created element's value always 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone please tell me why when I click on the [s] href created next to the list of names (myhand) generated it always says selection and i are 5?

```
var printDD = function(myhand, mydiv){
    var dtext = "";
    for(var i = 0;  i < myhand.length; i++){
        dtext += '<a href="#" id="dd'+i+'">[s]</a>' + myhand[i] + ', ';
    }

    mydiv.html(dtext);

    for(var i = 0;  i < myhand.length; i++){
        $('#dd'+i).click(function(){
        selection = i;
        console.log("sel: " + selection + " i: " + i);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows the last value

Comment: JamieJag, thank you. that fixed the problem. If you make your comment a answer I'll accept it as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take a look at [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). As the answer to that question says, you can create a function to return one, or you can use inline function invocation in the `for` loop like so:

```
for(var i = 0;  i < myhand.length; i++) {
    $('#dd'+i).click((function(x) {
        return function () {
            selection = x;
            console.log("sel: " + selection + " x: " + x);
        }
    }(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of `i` is determined at the time the click handler is run. So it will always have the value of `myhand.length - 1`, which is the state you left `i` in after the `for`-loop.